# Legend with color filling and shading lines in Base R

Tags: r, plot, legend, radix

In my plot I have two intersecting polygons, one colored and one with shading lines. 
In the legend I would like the two polygons and the intersection array represented correctly. 
Here is what I have:

```
plot(1:4, 1:4, type="n", xaxt="n", xlab="", yaxt="n", ylab="")
polygon(c(2,4,2), c(1,3,3), col="gray")
polygon(c(3,3,1), c(1,3,2), col="red", density=10)
legend("topleft", legend=c("A", "B", "AB"), fill=c("gray", "red", "gray"),
           density=c(NA, 10, NA), bty="n")
```

[image: Intersecting polygons, legend problem]

Is it possible to change the border color in the legend for B to red and add red shading lines to the symbol for AB?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should add argument `border=` to `legend()` to change the border color of small boxes and then add another call to `legend()` to overlay shading to AB box with your color. In the second `legend()` line I set `density=` for the AB to 10 and changed also `fill=` to red for the same box.

```
plot(1:4, 1:4, type="n", xaxt="n", xlab="", yaxt="n", ylab="")
polygon(c(2,4,2), c(1,3,3), col="gray")
polygon(c(3,3,1), c(1,3,2), col="red", density=10)
legend("topleft", legend=c("A", "B", "AB"), fill=c("gray", "red", "gray"),
       density=c(NA, 10, NA), bty="n",border=c("black", "red", "black")) 
legend("topleft", legend=c("A", "B", "AB"), fill=c("gray", "red", "red"),
       density=c(NA, 10, 10), bty="n",border=c("black", "red", "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Strange, if `bty` is set to "o" (=default), the gray background color of the AB-legend box disappears.

Comment: @Rob If you set bty="o" then legend box with white fill is plotted and so you don't see previous legend any more. Add also bg=NA to second call of legend() to make background transparent.